# Add a condition for two buttons when one of them isDisplayed to click on it?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have a problem with if(.isDisplayed()) else if (.isDisplayed()) else condition.

The isDisplayed() function doesn't work for this condition, it always enters in the first if block even the powderRinseStartButton is not in the DOM.

```
if (powderRinseStartButton != null && powderRinseStartButton.isDisplayed() && powderRinseStartButton.ispresent()) {
  powderRinseStartButton.click();
} else if (brewerRinseStartButton != null && brewerRinseStartButton.isDisplayed() && brewerRinseStartButton.ispresent()) {
  brewerRinseStartButton.click();
} else {
  fn.click();
}
```

if I put the first or second piece of code, it works fine

```
browser.wait(() => {
      return brewerRinseStartButton.isDisplayed().then(() => {
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(brewerRinseStartButton), delay).then(() =>
      {
          browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(brewerRinseStartButton), delay).then(() =>
          {
              expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(brewerRinseStartButton)).toBeTruthy();

                brewerRinseStartButton.click().then(() =>
                {
                   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(maintenanceText), 240000,
                                               'The Maintenance Text should be visible within 240s');
                   expect(maintenanceText.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
               });
           });
       });
    });

  // return powderRinseStartButton.isDisplayed().then(() => 
  // {
  //     browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(powderRinseStartButton), delay).then(() =>
  //     {
  //         browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(powderRinseStartButton), delay).then(() =>
  //         {
  //             expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(powderRinseStartButton)).toBeTruthy();

  //              powderRinseStartButton.click().then(() =>
  //              {
  //                  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(maintenanceText), 240000,
  //                                              'The Maintenance Text should be visible within 240s');
  //                  expect(maintenanceText.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  //              });
  //          });
  //      });
  //  });

}, 5000)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('return true')
    return true;
  }, () => {
    console.log('false');
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(fn), delay).then(() => {
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(fn), delay).then(() => {
        expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(fn)).toBeTruthy();
        fn.click();
      });
    });
  });
```

I want to make a condition if brewerRinseStartButton is showed than click on brewerRinseStartButton, elseif powderRinseStartButton is showed than click on powderRinseStartButton else dosomething.

I solved this problem.
The isDisplayed() 
@return
A promise that will be resolved with whether this element is currently visible on the page.
Wait for all promises to be resolved, or for any to be rejected.

```
       let failHandler = ()=>
        {
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(fn), delay).then(() =>
            {
                browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(fn), delay).then(() =>
                {
                    expect(fn.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
                    expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(fn)).toBeTruthy();
                    fn.click();
                });
            }); 
        };



        brewerRinseStartButton.isDisplayed().then(()=>
        {                               
            fnBrewer();

        },()=>
        {
            powderRinseStartButton.isDisplayed().then(()=>
            {                                  
                fnPowder();
            },()=>
            { 
                failHandler();
            });
        });
```

Comment: If the `powderRinseStartButton` is not in the DOM, but it still falls into the first branch of the `if` statement then it is in the DOM --- you might have multiple elements on the page matching the search criteria for `powderRinseStartButton`.

Answer (score 0):

IsDisplayed() function returns promise, so there are two ways to handle it. One as you also attempted to use then on returning promise object and perform action afterwards.
Second one is most correct and clean way to use async/await for handling promises

```
async clickStartButton() {
     if(powderRinseStartButton != null && await 
      powderRinseStartButton.isDisplayed() && await 
    powderRinseStartButton.ispresent())
  {
       await   powderRinseStartButton.click();
    }
   else if(brewerRinseStartButton != null && await 
   brewerRinseStartButton.isDisplayed() && await 
    brewerRinseStartButton.ispresent())
     {
     await   brewerRinseStartButton.click();
    }
    else
   {
       await fn.click();
       {}
     }
```

Note: I've used my mobile keypad for typing so please ignore the code identation

Comment: 1) If the powderRinseStartButton appears the first if condition works
2) If the brewerRinseStartButton appears the else if doesn't work
3) If the first and second button don't appear it doesn't enter to the else
It always enters the if condition

Answer (score 0):

I would probably attempt to do this by using the **or** functionality available in xpath locators. The logic is that you provide a single locator which contains the locators required to locate both objects. If the first locator is found it will be used, if the second is found it will be used. If neither are found then you can use your `ele.isDisplayed()` check and run your else condition on it.

```
let requiredEle = element(by.xpath('//button[@class="locator1" or @class="locator2"]');

requiredEle.isDisplayed().then(function(wasDisplayed){
    if(wasDisplayed){
      requiredEle.click();
    } else {
      //Your else actions
    }
})
* not tested
```

I would also advise using **isPresent** instead of isDisplayed if you can as isDisplayed throws an exception if the element is not present and I'm not exactly sure how that will behave in the above if statement.

Comment: I tried all of them, isPresent , isDisplayed it doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you share the HTML and the locators you are using for both buttons

Answer (score 0):

One hack you can try for this scenario is using .then() .catch() chain of promises here instead of if else. So in then you try for clicking first element button And in catch() you do not reject or throw error but instead you click on the second element button.
So in the function you can return like below:

```
return brewerRinseStartButton.isDisplayed()
  .then(() => brewerRinseStartButton.click())
  .catch(() => { 
    return powderRinseStartButton.isDisplayed()
     .then(() => powderRinseStartButton.click());
  });
```

```
Note: I've also used my mobile keypad for typing so please ignore the code identation. Also I assumed that first you want to try clicking (if found) on brewerRinseStartButton and then you want to try clicking on powderRinseStartButton.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this code. I hope this should solve your problem. I have refactored WaitForElement code seperately so that it can be used in both the cases.

```
async WaitForElement(element, timeout = 30000) {
        try {
            await browser.wait(function () {
                return element.isDisplayed()
                    .then((isDisplayed) => isDisplayed, () => false);
            }, timeout);
            await browser.wait(function () {
                return element.isPresent()
                    .then((isPresent) => isPresent, () => false);
            }, timeout);
            return true;
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            return false;
        }
    }




async clickStartButton() {
        // powderRinseStartButton  = element(define locator)
        //brewerRinseStartButton =  element(define locator)

        if (await this.WaitForElement(this.powderRinseStartButton)) {
            await powderRinseStartButton.click();
        } else if (await this.WaitForElement(this.brewerRinseStartButton)) {
            await brewerRinseStartButton.click();
        } else {
            //await fn.click();
        }
    }
```

Explanation:

First element.isDisplayed() function returns Promise object so if we put it into If condition then it will always return true that's why it will always pass through first If loop.

Second point is that browser.wait understand true/false, hence we have to resolve element.isDiplayed promise so that it never through exception and we can wait until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. This should definitely work for you.

```
const powderRinseStartButton= element(by.id('start_powder_rinse'); 
const brewerRinseStartButton = element(by.id('start_brewer_rinse');

if (await powderRinseStartButton.ispresent()) {
  await powderRinseStartButton.click();
} else if (await brewerRinseStartButton.ispresent()) {
  await brewerRinseStartButton.click();
} else {
 await fn.click();
}
```

if the button takes some time to load. try adding `sleep` before `if`.

Hope it helps you. Please share the error if the approach fails.